# getting row data of a dataframe by index giving an error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe and want to extract the data of a particular row.

My code

```
config = pd.read_excel('milo_config.xlsx',sheet_name='B2WL3') 
data = config.set_index('IPv6 Address')
```

config df looks like

```
   Block Floor               IPv6 Address  Serial ID
0    B2W    L3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:defa        25.0
1    B2W    L3   fd00::212:4b00:1957:e315       13.0
2    B2W    L3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:d661        16.0
3    B2W    L3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:da6b        17.0
4    B2W    L3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:de87        21.0
5    B2W    L3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:e314        12.0
6    B2W    L3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:e37e        18.0
7    B2W    L3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:da2e        23.0
8    B2W    L3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:e32c        22.0
9    B2W    L3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:f00e        26.0
10   B2W    L3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:da4b        27.0
```

and data df looks like

```
                          Block Floor  Serial ID
IPv6 Address                                    
fd00::212:4b00:1957:defa    B2W    L3       25.0
fd00::212:4b00:1957:e315    B2W    L3       13.0
fd00::212:4b00:1957:d661    B2W    L3       16.0
fd00::212:4b00:1957:da6b    B2W    L3       17.0
fd00::212:4b00:1957:de87    B2W    L3       21.0
fd00::212:4b00:1957:e314    B2W    L3       12.0
fd00::212:4b00:1957:e37e    B2W    L3       18.0
fd00::212:4b00:1957:da2e    B2W    L3       23.0
fd00::212:4b00:1957:e32c    B2W    L3       22.0
```

when i try to extract a row using a particular address/index by

```
data.loc['fd00::212:4b00:1957:eb84']
```

I am getting an error `KeyError: 'fd00::212:4b00:1957:eb84'`

I don't understand why, I have tried extracting the row data earlier using the same way. I don't understand why its not happening now. Am i missing something ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is possible some traling whitespaces? `print (df.index.tolist())` ? Or only want select value which not exist?

Comment: Like jezrael said, does your index names have whitespaces? Also, check if it exists in your index: `'fd00::212:4b00:1957:eb84' in df.index`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, its because of the whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

There is problem whitespaces in index values, so remove it before selecting by `strip`:

```
df.index = df.index.str.strip()
```

Or:

```
df = df.rename(lambda x: x.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check whether 'fd00::212:4b00:1957:eb84' exits in the index of the data frame. this Error suggests that key is not exits in the index of the data frame

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the column name when addressing:

`data[data['IPv6 Address'] == 'fd00::212:4b00:1957:eb84']`